# Failing to download pandas_datareader package in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pandas-datareader

When I try to download the package using the GitHub URL it tells me I have an error. I attached a screenshot for this particular issue.

[image: Screenshot for above mess]

I have also tried to install it through the console and it successfully ran but it does not show in my installed packages in PyCharm. When I go to the folder the packages are in it is there so i try to make PyCharm recognize it but I am told the setup.py file does not exists.

I also tried to download the zip file and unpack it in the right folder and try to install it that way in PyCharm and it still fails. In this file the setup.py file exists but I am still told it does not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried the recommended way in the [pandas_readers documentation quickstart](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#quick-start)?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: sorry on the picture. figured since it was not actual code that it would be easier to view what was happening @tripleee

Comment: Well, i was not signed into GitHub in the setting panel. package install successful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so your problem is that you dont have git installed in your system. In windows its just a file executable for LINUX you can visit https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/pip-install-git/

Comment: So I am able to use all the git commands in my console. I was able to download the branch successfully and it is in the correct folder. But it is still not being recognized by PyCharm.

Comment: It happens sometimes have you tried git --version ? Just to be sure that you have git installed because that's what the error says that the git command is unrecognizable. One more approach could be like you can try installing some other libs just like you are trying to do this one.. If the error persists than it is most probably your git issue. Try upgrading your Git then..

Comment: One more thing you can try is adding the Git to your PATH. Just Google on how to do it.. and also try upgrading your pip too. Sometimes configs can be a mess!

Comment: Well, I was not signed into GitHub in the setting panel. package install successful. Thank you for your help!